# What threading pratice is good 90% of the time?

Tags: multithreading, multicore

What practice or practices are good 90% of the time when working with threading with multiple cores?

Personally all i have done was share immutable classes and pass (copy) data to a queue to the destine thread.

Comment: "What practice or practices are good 90% of the time when working with threading with multiple cores?

" - Best Practice: Don't!

Comment: "Uncontrolled access to shared variables"

Comment: @Mitch: That's unfair, I think - threading isn't something we should ignore.

Comment: Why would you want to use practices that fail 10% of the time?

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Yes it is: until you have identified a real bottleneck, don't do it. Treat it like optimisation (as you know)

Comment: @Neil Bartlett: I dont mean will fial 10% of the time. I mean is a good choose 90% of the time while 10% there is another better choice or this specific one will be more of a hassle to use

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I am researching. I dont know much about this and so far one technique was 'all i needed'

Comment: @acidzombie24
 the one technique you need is: Don't do it!  It will end in tears!

Comment: Read Threading in C#: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Answer (score 0):

This is very vague - but there are a few basic precepts I'd always follow:

1. Make sure threading makes sense before you implement it
2. Focus on algorithms, not individual lines of code when designing for threading
3. Thread at the highest level possible
4. Prefer immutable data
5. Synchronize data access appropriately
6. Prefer high level threading libraries over low level, hand written threading code
7. Measure (make sure 1. was true!)